# Docker Container: Access private endpoint that requires VPN - SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL

Tags: docker, ssl, openssl

on my localhost machine that is **on a VPN**. If I run
`curl https://foo.bar/api/v1/19` I will get a bunch of returned data.

then I spin up a docker container with mounted cert on my local host as follow:

```
docker run \
    -p 6709:6709 -p 6708:6708 \
    -v /etc/ssl/certs:/etc/ssl/certs:rw \
    IMAGE \
    "update-ca-certificates"
```

from within the container, I cannot access the same endpoint

```
root@1349b12fdff2:/# curl -v https://foo.bar/api/v1/19
*   Trying 10.132.123.123...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to foo.bar (10.132.123.123) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to foo.bar:443 
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to foo.bar:443
```

Any ideas?

Comment: actually I think I found the solution is to run the container with `--net=host`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution is to run the container with `--net=host`